# Get click of imageview(added dynamically) within a row of uitableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a tableview whose rows are dynamic and each row have n numbers of imageviews as it is in the screenshot attached [image: Row of the tableview cell]

Now what I want is to know which imageview I have clicked.

NOTE : imageview is added dynamically to one view and that view is added to scrollview so that it can scroll horizontally.

And there are n numbers of row in a tableview.

EDIT: 
I tried adding simple button as well above the image view just to try out if that clicks but its click also didn't work.

I tried the solution of Gesture as well but that also didn't work

**CODE**:

```
-(UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *strrowId ;

    UITableViewCell  *cell = [_tblviewScroll1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellOne"];


        // create and add labels to the contentView
        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:231.0/255.0 blue:231.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

       // cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        scrollView1 = (UIScrollView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];

        [scrollView1  setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

        scrollView1.delegate = self;

        NSArray* subviews1 = [scrollView1 subviews];
            for (UIView* subview in subviews1) {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }

        if (scrollView1.contentOffset.y > 0  ||  scrollView1.contentOffset.y < 0 )
            scrollView1.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView1.contentOffset.x, 0);



    [scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:231.0/255.0 blue:231.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    [scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;

    scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES

    scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;




        for (int i = 0; i <mutSubTitle.count; i++)
        {
            NSString *ids = @"";



                UIView *viewvertically1;
                viewvertically1=[[UIView alloc]init];
                viewvertically1.tag = (i+1);
                [viewvertically1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                [viewvertically1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

                //Displaying image

                NSString *strImgUrl = @"https://img.xxxx.com/";
                NSString *strimge=[mutSubImag objectAtIndex:i];
                strImgUrl = [strImgUrl stringByAppendingString:strimge];

                NSURL *url = strImgUrl;

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:url];

                UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


                 imageView.frame= CGRectMake(0, 10, 170, 110);

                imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
                [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

                // images with Lazy Loading

                [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];


                UITapGestureRecognizer *imgTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureTapEvent:)];


                imgTapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;


                [imageView addGestureRecognizer:imgTapGesture];

                [viewvertically1 addSubview:imageView];
                [viewvertically1 addSubview:lblDesc];

                [scrollView1 addSubview:viewvertically1];
                //[cell bringSubviewToFront:scrollView1];

        }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method  add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` for your Concept

```
// by default the imageview userInteraction is disable you need to manually enable
cell.yourimageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
// the following line used for assign the different tags for eachImage
cell.yourimageView.tag = indexPath.row;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ImageTapped:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.yourimageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

finally need to check which imageView was clicked, check the flag in selector method

```
-(void)ImageTapped :(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
  // you can get tag in which image is selected
     NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);
}
```

Comment: I tried this thing but it is not going in the selector method
 [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
UITapGestureRecognizer *imgTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureTapEvent:)];
imgTapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:imgTapGesture];

-(void)gestureTapEvent:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    
    UIView *view = gesture.view;
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)view.tag);
}'

Comment: this is not for tablview , you added for some where else

Comment: @Anub.Karthik it is in the didSelectForRowAtindexpath

Comment: no bro ,it is wrong to added , that the reason you can't get the selector , you need to add this is **CellForRowAtIndexpath**,

Comment: can you send your code to my mail Id karthik.saral@gmail.com, I will check and tell to u

Comment: Sorry my mistake its in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: can you update the question it is easy to solve,.else we cant find where the problem will occur

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a button instead of image view added to a view. Assign the image to button's backgroundImageView. You can then give actions for the buttons

Comment: I tried adding a button on imageview just for testing purpose to see if that can help me but the click of button also didnt worked

Comment: No I told to add a button instead of imageView. You can assign the image to backgroundImageView of the button

Comment: "imageview is added dynamically to one view and that view is added to scrollview" - you can replace this entire thing with a button. Add this button to your scroll view and give action for the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use UIButton as @Arun says or the imageview ur using currently add button on Image with clear background color and add tag to that button and use that click action.

Comment: I did this thing as well but no luck , i have edited my question

Comment: OK as per my understanding u wnat to show table and each row have multiple images right?
so that u can scroll vertically for multiple row and horizontly for multiple image

Comment: hey Megz let me know fast, IM leaving in next 5 mins

Comment: Then the easiest way is to use collection view instead of table view
Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/

Comment: how can u use both  scroll @arun

Comment: its meghal.j.adesra@gmail.com

Comment: Answer is just collection view Vijay :)
Collection View is similar to tableView but allows to have multiple cells within a single row

Comment: hey megz i was out of city for last 2 days have you got solution for same if not yet then start chat with me i will explain each code how to implement it